# Twitter Card - Image with port not showing, but showing without port

Tags: meta-tags, social-media, twitter, open-graph-protocol, twitter-card

Images without port is working. But if image with port, it won't load.

Those images with port are not loading:

https://webro.ml:8083/images/sprite.png?1446554103
https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/uploads/5b9be7d31857d.jpg

But this image without port is loading  https://www.findmyprofession.com/assets/images/job-opportunities/google.jpg

I test this link http://seo-test.webro.ml/index23.html

My twitts: https://twitter.com/alexanderMyrav1

The [Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started.html) says to add **robots.txt**, but didn't help.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimesbits"/>
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nickbilton"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/12/08/a-twitter-for-my-sister/"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="index23 A Twitter for My Sister kepa"/>
    <meta
        property="og:description"
        content="index23 the early days, Twitter grew so quickly that it was almost impossible to add new features because engineers spent their time trying to keep the rocket ship from stalling."
    />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/uploads/5b9be7d31857d.jpg"/>
    <meta
        property="og:image:secure_url"
        content="https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/uploads/5b9be7d31857d.jpg"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi index23</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Maybe something with ssl?

Twitter refuses load images with ports?

Comment: "You need to add metatags for image width and height" --  Sorry I think I mixed it up with Facebook's Opengraph. Did you dl all the steps listed at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/troubleshooting-cards#missing_text ?

Comment: Have you tried the [card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)?

Comment: Yes, i tried. It says no errors.

Comment: I dld all the steps. It didn't help.

Comment: While we volunteer our time and are here to help, following a handful of links so that we can understand what you need is less desireable than having you provide your code and images to the body of your question. It will make it easier for us to help you.